# Django URL regex to accept no number or any number till 99

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a url like this

```
test/report
```

and

```
test/report/1
```

and i want to write a matching url regex using django

I tried out this

```
 url(r'^test/report/(0?\d+)/$'
```

but it did not work . Can any one know how to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to create two regexes, one without the slash, and another including the slash:

```
url(r'^test/report$'

url(r'^test/report/(\d\d?)$
```

Comment: well that cannot be done . Um only allow a single url with a single view. Thank you.

Comment: what does forbid you to specify the **same** view for both patterns? see here: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter08.html

Comment: seems like he s having a point though the url will be repeated

Answer (score 1):

lenik's answer is generally the proper way, but if you must have it in a single regex, you should be able to use this:

```
url(r'^test/report(/\d\d?)?$')
# Meaning:
# (   Start contents of a node
# /   A slash
# \d  A digit
# \d? A second digit, or nothing
# )?  Finish node. Must find everything in the node, or nothing
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you please try with `url(r'^test/report/\d{1,2}/$'` instead ?

Comment: with this pattern ah Evlikosh mentioned we cannot use test/report  it will fail, and your syntax is missing parentheses .